# JW player autostart not working on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer7

I am using jwplayer in my site, I have included the player using iframe. I have included the player js script.

```
<script src="//content.jwplatform.com/libraries/playerid.js"></script>
```

then iframe with the source.

```
<div style="position:relative; padding-bottom:56.25%; overflow:hidden;">
    <iframe src="//content.jwplatform.com/players/MEDIAID-PLAYERID.html" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" allowfullscreen style="position:absolute;"></iframe>
</div>
```

When the user clicks on a cover image, I will reload the source of the iframe

```
video_block.attr("src", src);
```

It was worked on my mobile till last week.(15-March-2017). Now it is not working on mobile devices, I saw they are [saying](https://www.jwplayer.com/blog/mobile-web-autoplay/) support for autostart on mobile devices. I am not sure the latest release has an effect.

My extracted testing code(this simple code itself not autostart on mobiles, although the corresponding player is autostart enabled):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        IFRAME SAMPLE
    </title>

</head>

<body>
<div style="position:relative; padding-bottom:56.25%; overflow:hidden;"><iframe src="//content.jwplatform.com/players/mediaid-playerid.html" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" allowfullscreen style="position:absolute;"></iframe></div>
<script src="https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/playerid.js"></script><!-- Featured Video Card Player -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately auto-play is officially disabled in android and has been disabled in IOS for a long time. There is no option to play a video automatically in any major mobile device anymore. ( of course on a web page )

Comment: No, check this link, https://www.jwplayer.com/blog/mobile-web-autoplay/ 

I tried it on my android mobile it works.

Comment: so I think your answer is at https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay most probably because of iframe.

Comment: But again, the links using iframe only. :(

Comment: Also you need to give a physical filepath as source to video tags. But with iframes you can use youtube, facebook and more URLs.